# SpellNum_Dollar module converting only one part, second part

Tags: vba, excel

I wanted a visual basic in excel code to convert numbers into text. The code is already available on Microsoft site, but I wanted more specific one. So someone helped me and edited the Microsoft's code. It worked fine, but one critical problem occurred. I asked him for help but he is not responding anymore.

The problem is that if there is two parts, only the first part is written.

For example: 284,323.00 is written as "Two hundred eighty-four thousand dollars only"

877,666.00 is written as "Eight hundred seventy-seven thousand dollars only"

I want the full number to be converted into text like this : "877,666.00 > Eight hundred seventy-seven thousand six hundred sixty-six dollars only"

Can you help me correct the code?

This is the code:

```
Option Explicit
'Main Function
Function SpellNum_Dollar(ByVal MyNumber As Variant) As String
    Dim Dollars, Cents, Temp, D
    Dim DecimalPlace, Count
    ReDim Place(9) As String
    Place(2) = " Thousand "
    Place(3) = " Million "
    Place(4) = " Billion "
    Place(5) = " Trillion "
    ' String representation of amount.
    MyNumber = Trim(Str(MyNumber))
    ' Position of decimal place 0 if none.
    DecimalPlace = InStr(MyNumber, ".")
    ' Convert Cents and set MyNumber to dollars amount.
    If DecimalPlace > 0 Then
        Cents = GetTens(Left(Mid(MyNumber, DecimalPlace + 1) & _
                  "00", 2))
        MyNumber = Trim(Left(MyNumber, DecimalPlace - 1))
    End If
    Count = 1
    Do While MyNumber <> ""
        Temp = GetHundreds(Right(MyNumber, 3))
        If Temp <> "" Then Dollars = Temp & Place(Count) & D
        If Len(MyNumber) > 3 Then
            MyNumber = Left(MyNumber, Len(MyNumber) - 3)
        Else
            MyNumber = ""
        End If
        Count = Count + 1
    Loop
    Select Case Dollars
        Case ""
            Dollars = "No Dollars"
        Case "One"
            Dollars = "One Dollar"
         Case Else
            Dollars = Dollars & " Dollars"
    End Select
     Select Case Cents
        Case ""
            Cents = ""
        Case "One"
            Cents = " and One Cent"
              Case Else
            Cents = " and " & Cents & " Cents"
     End Select
    SpellNum_Dollar = LowerCaseWords(Dollars & Cents)
End Function

' Converts a number from 100-999 into text
Function GetHundreds(ByVal MyNumber)
    Dim Result As String
    If Val(MyNumber) = 0 Then Exit Function
    MyNumber = Right("000" & MyNumber, 3)
    ' Convert the hundreds place.
    If Mid(MyNumber, 1, 1) <> "0" Then
        Result = GetDigit(Mid(MyNumber, 1, 1)) & " Hundred "
    End If
    ' Convert the tens and ones place.
    If Mid(MyNumber, 2, 1) <> "0" Then
        Result = Result & GetTens(Mid(MyNumber, 2))
    Else
        Result = Result & GetDigit(Mid(MyNumber, 3))
    End If
    GetHundreds = Result
End Function

' Converts a number from 10 to 99 into text.
Function GetTens(TensText)
    Dim Result As String
    Result = ""           ' Null out the temporary function value.
    If Val(Left(TensText, 1)) = 1 Then   ' If value between 10-19...
        Select Case Val(TensText)
            Case 10: Result = "Ten"
            Case 11: Result = "Eleven"
            Case 12: Result = "Twelve"
            Case 13: Result = "Thirteen"
            Case 14: Result = "Fourteen"
            Case 15: Result = "Fifteen"
            Case 16: Result = "Sixteen"
            Case 17: Result = "Seventeen"
            Case 18: Result = "Eighteen"
            Case 19: Result = "Nineteen"
            Case Else
        End Select
    Else                                 ' If value between 20-99...
        Select Case Val(Left(TensText, 1))
            Case 2: Result = "Twenty-"
            Case 3: Result = "Thirty-"
            Case 4: Result = "Forty-"
            Case 5: Result = "Fifty-"
            Case 6: Result = "Sixty-"
            Case 7: Result = "Seventy-"
            Case 8: Result = "Eighty-"
            Case 9: Result = "Ninety-"
            Case Else
        End Select
        Result = Result & GetDigit _
            (Right(TensText, 1))  ' Retrieve ones place.
    End If
    If Right(Result, 1) = "-" Then
        Result = Left(Result, Len(Result) - 1)
    End If
    GetTens = Result
End Function

' Converts a number from 1 to 9 into text.
Function GetDigit(Digit)
    Select Case Val(Digit)
        Case 1: GetDigit = "One"
        Case 2: GetDigit = "Two"
        Case 3: GetDigit = "Three"
        Case 4: GetDigit = "Four"
        Case 5: GetDigit = "Five"
        Case 6: GetDigit = "Six"
        Case 7: GetDigit = "Seven"
        Case 8: GetDigit = "Eight"
        Case 9: GetDigit = "Nine"
        Case Else: GetDigit = ""
    End Select
End Function

Function LowerCaseWords(MyNumber As String) As String

    'Splits the number into an array and then loops through the array, starting at the second word, and lower cases all of them
    'Just need to check if the first word has a dash, if so, the first letter after the dash will be lower cased
    Const ArrayLoopStart As Long = 1
    Dim WordArray As Variant
    Dim WordCounter As Long
    Dim FindDash As Long

    WordArray = Split(MyNumber, " ")
    FindDash = InStr(1, WordArray(0), "-")

    If FindDash > 0 Then
        WordArray(0) = Left(WordArray(0), FindDash) & LCase(Mid(WordArray(0), FindDash + 1, 1)) & Right(WordArray(0), Len(WordArray(0)) - 1 - FindDash)
    End If

    For WordCounter = ArrayLoopStart To UBound(WordArray)
        WordArray(WordCounter) = LCase(WordArray(WordCounter))
    Next WordCounter

    LowerCaseWords = Join(WordArray, " ")

End Function
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but isn't `and` reserved for decimals? _One Hundred Twenty Seven Dollars **and** Fourteen Cents_

Comment: Change `& D` to `& Dollars`.  It won't put the "and" between the thousands portion and the hundreds/tens/digits portion, but that isn't normal anyway.

Comment: Thank you. Yeah I wrote "and" by mistake.

Comment: FWIW - I suspect your `LowerCaseWords` function can be shortened to just `LowerCaseWords = Left(MyNumber, 1) & LCase(Mid(MyNumber, 2))`